# Clean the gene names in a dataframe

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have an R dataframe that looks like this:

```
       Gene Symbol       Prom 1       Prom 2    Prom 3
 1 Gm16088  // Gm16088    7.168819  7.410547  7.634662
 2             Gm26206    7.006416  6.824151  6.941721
 3   Gm1992  // Gm1992    6.750240  6.591182  6.479798
 4             Gm10568    4.390371  4.496734  4.672061
 5             Gm22307   13.196217 13.157953 13.601210
 6 Gm16041  // Gm16041    5.146015  5.450036  5.388205
 7 Gm17101  // Gm17101    6.434086  6.752058  6.603427
```

In the gene symbol column, I have some gene symbols that are repeated several times inside the same cell of the dataframe. In some lines, the gene symbol is repeated a hundred of times. Is there a way to solve this, in order to have the lines like this:

```
Gene Symbol       Prom 1       Prom 2    Prom 3
 1 Gm16088       7.168819  7.410547  7.634662
```

Instead of having them like this:

```
Gene Symbol       Prom 1       Prom 2    Prom 3
 1 Gm16088  // Gm16088    7.168819  7.410547  7.634662
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could also use `word`

```
library(stringr)
word(x, 1)
#[1] "Gm16088" "Gm26206"
```

#### data

```
 x <- c("Gm16088  // Gm16088", "Gm26206")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `gsub()`:

```
x <- "Gm16088  // Gm16088"

> gsub("\\s*//.*", "", x)
[1] "Gm16088"
```

In your actual code, you would replace `x` with:

```
df$`Gene Symbol`
```

where `df` is the name of the data frame.